# Why did Izumo's familiars attack her in Blue Exorcist?

Tags: blue-exorcist

So I read the Manga and also watched the anime. There is an arc in the Manga that is not in the anime, the Illuminati arc where Izumo is kidnapped and taken to the Illuminati lair.

Those fox spirits, even if they hate her are like family to her. She considers them as her brothers. They went so far to lay down their lives for her then.

I don't get why would they attack her like that in the earlier episodes of the anime during one of the exorcist exams. Izumo was with her friend in the girl's bathroom where they were attacked and on summoning the spirits, they turned on her. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Familiars in the manga are actually tamed demons. If the user is not properly trained in controlling them or have a disturbed state of mind then the go out of control. Before Izumo was attacked by ghouls, Paku said she was going to quit the course. Hence she was in a disturbed state of mind. So the familiars attacked her.
According to wiki about her foxes

> White Foxes appear to be very proud, even willing to turn against those they've been raised with if they sense weakness.

Comment: Yes I get that. But her familiars were like her family. She called them their brothers and they risked their lives for her while fighting a demon far stronger than them. Something only someone very close can do. How can someone like that attack her just because she was a bit weak?

Comment: @BlackKnigh7 they are still demons. Don't forget that even the blue exorcists own half brothers are all up for killing him if they think it would serve their needs....or that it would be fun.

Comment: But does it make sense for them to die for her if they are so benefit conscious? They almost died at the hands of Shima.

Answer (score 1):

It was stated in an episode (I don't remember which, or the exact quote) That any sign of weakness in the owner would result in hostility from the summoned familiars.

This is because the familiars, which all happen to be demons, do not wish to have the dishonour of serving and being under command of a "weak" ruler. Thus they attack when they sense weakness, removing the contract between owner and familiar.

Comment: Yes I get that. But her familiars were like her family. She called them their brothers and they risked their lives for her while fighting a demon far stronger than them. Something only someone very close can do. How can someone like that attack her just because she was a bit weak?

Comment: I believe it is a very valid question. In the manga, during the Illuminati arc where Izumo was taken back to her town, the familiars really helped her out. Really like laying down their lives for her. It's hard to believe why someone like that would attack her just because she was weak.